# Receiving the following error when a sf object is cropped:Error in CPL_geos_op2(op, x, y):Evaluation error:TopologyException:Input geom 0 is invalid:

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a strange error I receive when I try to crop a `sf` object I would like to plot in `R` using a different projection and `ggplot2` and `sf` packages. To elaborate on that, when I run the following code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(showtext)
library(showtextdb)
library(ggtext)

sf_use_s2(FALSE)

lakes <- maps::map("lakes", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_crop(xmin = -140, xmax = -55, ymin = 15, ymax = 50) %>%
  st_transform(crs = st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100"))
```

it throws the following error;

```
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that
they are planar
Error in CPL_geos_op2(op, x, y) : 
  Evaluation error: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Nested shells at -88.554344177246094 50.02197265625.
```

And when I change the `ymax` argument from 50 to 45, it runs smoothly without error. I could not understand why I receive such a strange error. I saw something similar on the web [in this link](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1411) However, I could not understand why such an error occurs and what I should be doing to overcome that. Thank you for your attention beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling spherical geometry with `sf_use_s2(FALSE)` causes `st_crop` to stumble over the still spherical lon/lat coordinates. You could either leave `sf_use_s2(TRUE)` or `st_transform` to planar coordinates *before* cropping (with cropping limits given in the new coordinates).